# Finding why OBR considers a bundle to be required

Tags: osgi, bnd, obr, bndtools

Is there a simple way to understand why Bndtools OBR resolution has decided it needs a particular bundle to satisfy the run requirements? In my particular case, I have all `org.slf4j.*` packages in `-runsystempackages`, but it still insists on including `slf4j-api`.

Answer (score 1):

Are there bundle fragments involved? Fragments need to be installed into a host bundle, and in the case of SLF4J, the static binding mechanism is expecting to be installed into the slf4j.api bundle.